# Parsing webpage into a regular expression in python: Why is the end of my sentence being cut off?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I parsed [this](http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/hemolytik/display_sub.php?details=1001) webpage using this code:

```
for i in range(1001,1002):
   web_page = 'http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/hemolytik/display_sub.php?details=' + str(i)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(web_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    soup_text = soup.get_text()
    formatted_fileopen = StringIO.StringIO(soup_text).readlines()
    list_to_parse = [unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',i).encode('ascii','ignore').strip() for i in formatted_fileopen if i.strip() != '']
    for item in list_to_parse:
            regex = re.search('Primary informationHemolytik',item)
            if regex:
                    print ''.join(item.strip().split()[:-6])
```

The output of the above code is this:

```
'1001detailsPrimaryinformationHemolytikID1002PMID10660589YEAR2000SEQUENCEALWMTLLKKVLKAAAKAALNAVLVGANALENGTH28NAMES4C-terModificationFreeN-terModificationFreeLinear/CyclicLinearStereochemistryLModifiedResiduesNoneFUNCTIONAntimicrobialACTIVITYLC50=1.40.2MRBCsSOURCEHumanSecondary'
```

And I want the output to be readable, like this:

```
[1001,1002,10660589,2000,ALWMTLLKKVLKAAAKAALNAVLVGANA,28,S4,Free,Free,Linear,L,None,AntiMicrobial,LC50=1.40, HumanSecondary]
```

I wrote this regular expression to parse the line:

```
regex = re.search(r'([0-9]+)\w+HemolytikID([0-9]+)\w+PMID([0-9]+)\w+YEAR([0-9]+)\SEQUENCE([A-Z]+)\LENGTH([0-9]+)\NAMES([A-Za-z0-9]+)\C-terModification([A-Za-z]+)\N-terModification([A-Za-z]+)\Linear\/Cyclic([A-Za-z]+)\Stereochemistry([A-Z])\ModifiedResidues([A-Za-z]+)\FUNCTION([A-Za-z]+)\ACTIVITY([A-Za-z0-9\=\.]+)\RBCsSource([A-Za-z]+)\Secondary',line)
```

The problem is when I get to the part: \ACTIVITY([A-Za-z0-9\=.]+) ; I don't think I'm accounting for equal signs and decimal points properly. Could someone show me where I'm going wrong?

(Alternatively if someone had an easier way to parse the webpage in the first place that would also be great, but I'm at the limit of what I have the ability to do with my code above).

Edit 1, in response to JonRSharpe comment below; When I run the above code up to the line list_to_parse = XX and print list_to_parse, this is the output. And I'm not sure of an easier way to extract the information I want (basically the information stored in the table, that I'm trying to get from my regular expression) :

```
['Hemolytik: Database of hemolytic peptides', '#myslideshow{ /*sample CSS for demo*/', 'border:2px solid black;', '}', '/***********************************************', '* Translucent slideshow- (c) Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)', '* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use', '* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more.', '***********************************************/', 'var parentAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("parentAccordion");', 'parentAccordion.init("acc","h3",0,0);', 'var nestedAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("nestedAccordion");', 'nestedAccordion.init("nested","h3",1,-1,"acc-selected");', '$(document).ready(function(){', '$("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled - Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav', '$("ul.topnav li span").hover(function() { //When trigger is clicked...', '//Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)', '$(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown(\'fast\').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click', '$(this).parent().hover(function() {', '}, function(){', '$(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp(\'slow\'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up', '});', '//Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)', '}).hover(function() {', '$(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"', '}, function(){  //On Hover Out', '$(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"', '});', '});', 'body {  position: absolute;}', '#cssm1 *  { padding:12; margin: -7; font: 1em arial; }', '#cssm1 { position: absolute;  z-index: 99; margin: 0 auto; float: centre; line-height: 20px; }', '#cssm1 a { display: block; border: 1px solid #fff; background: #000000;repeat-x; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 8px 7px 6px;font-size:1.4em; }', '#cssm1 a:hover { background: #789; color: #FFFFFF;}', '#cssm1 ul li, #cssm1 ul li ul li  { width: 130px; list-style-type:none; }', '#cssm1 ul li { float: left; width: 131px; }', '#cssm1 ul li ul, #cssm1:hover ul li ul, #cssm1:hover ul li:hover ul li ul{', 'display:none;', 'list-style-type:none;', 'width: 151px;', '}', '#cssm1:hover ul, #cssm1:hover ul li:hover ul, #cssm1:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {', 'display:block;', '}', '#cssm1:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {', 'position: absolute;', 'margin-left: 131px;', 'margin-top: -20px;', '}', '#button', '{', 'background:;', 'position:relative;', 'width:80px;', 'height:10px;', 'line-height:5px;', 'display:block;', 'border:0px solid #dadada;', 'margin:-17px 0 0 20px;', 'text-align:center;', '}', '#buttontwo', '{', 'background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;', 'border: 0px solid #DADADA ;', 'color: white;', 'width:100px;', 'height: 0;', 'overflow:hidden;', 'left: 0;', 'line-height: 30px;', 'position: absolute;', 'top: 40px;', 'border-radius: 15px;', '}', '#button:hover > #buttontwo', '{', 'display:block;', 'left:-7px;', 'height:30px;', '}', 'Home Page', 'HEMOLYTIK: A Database of Hemolytic and Non-hemolytic Peptides', 'SEARCH', 'Basic', 'Conditional', 'Peptide', 'SMILES', 'CATEGORIZATION', 'Source', 'Peptide Type', 'Function', 'Length', 'SIMILARITY', 'BLAST', 'Smith-Waterman', 'Mapping', 'Alignment', 'DOWNLOAD', 'Sequence', 'Structure', 'Refrences', 'Datasets', 'IMPORTANT', 'Submit Form', 'Statistics', 'Guide/Help', 'Recent Papers', 'GENERAL', 'Acknowledgment', 'Important Links', 'Developers', 'Contact', 'Detailed description page of Hemolytik', 'This page displays user query in tabular form.', '1001  details Primary informationHemolytik ID1001PMID10660589YEAR2000SEQUENCEALWMTLLKKVLKAAAKAALNAVLVGANALENGTH28NAMES4C-ter ModificationFreeN-ter ModificationFreeLinear/CyclicLinearStereochemistryLModified ResiduesNoneFUNCTIONAntimicrobialACTIVITYLC50 =1.40.2MRBCs SOURCEHumanSecondary informationPropertiesPhysico-Chemical detailsSTRUCTURENatural StructureFinal StructureDSSP statesCHHHHHHHHHHHHHTTTGGGSSCCCSCCSMILESN[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC(C)C)C(=O)N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]c(C)c1CC)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCSC)C(=O)N[C@@H]([C@@H](C)O)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC(C)C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC(C)C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](C(C)C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC(C)C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC(C)C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC(=O)N)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](C(C)C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC(C)C)C(=O)N[C@@H](C(C)C)C(=O)NCC(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)N[C@@H](CC(=O)N)C(=O)N[C@@H](C)C(=O)OExternal Links', 'PDB exactPDB partialSP exactSP partialTrEMBL exactTrEMBL partialIEDB exactIEDB partial', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'Reference InformaitonARTICLEStructure-activity relationship study of antimicrobial dermaseptin S4 showing the consequences of peptide oligomerization on selective cytotoxicity.AUTHORSFeder R,Dagan AJOURNALJ Biol Chem. 2000 Feb 11;275(6):4230-8.', '#button', '{', 'background:;', 'position:relative;', 'width:80px;', 'height:10px;', 'line-height:5px;', 'display:block;', 'border:0px solid #dadada;', 'margin:-17px 0 0 20px;', 'text-align:center;', '}', '#buttontwo', '{', 'background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;', 'border: 0px solid #DADADA ;', 'color: white;', 'width:100px;', 'height: 0;', 'overflow:hidden;', 'left: 0;', 'line-height: 30px;', 'position: absolute;', 'top: 40px;', 'border-radius: 15px;', '}', '#button:hover > #buttontwo', '{', 'display:block;', 'left:-7px;', 'height:30px;', '}', 'Hemolytik', "Raghava's Group", 'IMTECH', 'CSIR', 'CRDD', 'GPSR Package']
```

Edit 2: Using Jan's tool below, I was able to construct this regular expression that works:

`([0-9]+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)SEQUENCE([A-Z]+)LENGTH([0-9]+)NAME([A-Z0-9]+)C-terModification([A-Za-z]+)N-ter Modification([A-Za-z]+)Linear/Cyclic([A-Za-z]+)Stereochemistry([A-Za-z]+)Modified Residues([A-Za-z]+)FUNCTION([A-Za-z0-9]+)ACTIVITY([A-Z0-9]+)\s\=([0-9\.]+)([A-Za-z])RBCs SOURCE([A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions, given that you already have an HTML parser in use? If it's a specific problem applying one regex to a particular string then give a [mcve] *of that*, but more likely that's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: You have some serious problems there, for instance you are escaping some letters like `L`, `F`,`N` that do not need to be escaped while others like `\S` do mean sth. different than `S`. Your [**expression does not even match the line**](https://regex101.com/r/xTFu4U/1). Additionally, `\A` matches the very beginning of a string not the letter `A`.

Comment: JonRSharpe, thank you for your comment, I appreciate it. As described above (I have edited question to show output), when I use the HTML parser, the output is what I've added in to the question above, and I can't see an easier way of getting the information that I want? Do you think that a regular expression isn't suitable here, and instead I should spend time fixing the parser?

Comment: Jan, thank you for your comment, I appreciate it too. Given JonRSharpe's comment above, perhaps a regular expression is not the correct approach for this situation. That tool you provided is fantastic, thank you so much. It'll be really useful!

Comment: Jan, I used your tool to make a complete regular expression. I really appreciate it, much easier to see what's going on (Edited question above to show regular expression). This method is clearly still not perfect, as JonRSharpe says it would be easier to just parse the HTML file, but as you can see above it doesn't parse very nicely. Thank you both.